Expectation of the inverse of an estimator using delta method linearization
I'm working on a research internship about the precision of consumption price indexes and face some probems that leads me to ask a lot of questions about the methods I used and need to be answered.
Some words about my project
The purpose of my study is to measure the precision of consumption price indexes at several levels of aggregation of varieties of products in Réunion Islands, this study will lead to help the NSI on whether or not a price index is acceptably precise enough to be diffusable, namely to know if the price indexes of fruits and vegetables or other alimentary products that suffered of high price increase can be released for the locals.
The Problem
We consider a random variable $\frac{1}{\hat{\bar{P}}_0}$ an estimator by substitution of $\hat{\bar{P}}_0$ where $\hat{\bar{P^0}} = \dfrac{1}{n} \displaystyle\sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} p_{i}^0$ is the estimated mean of n i.i.d. variables $p_{i}^0$. By the CLT, we know that
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\bar{P^0}}-\bar{P^0}\right) \rightarrow^d \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_0^2) $$
when $\mathbb{E}(p_{i}^0) = \bar{P^0}$ and $Var(p_{i}^0) = \sigma_0^2$.
We want to calculate exactly $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{\hat{\bar{P}}_0}\right)$.
So to do this, I used a similar thinking of a method as the Delta Method by using a Taylor Expansion of $f(\hat{\bar{P^0}})=1/\hat{\bar{P^0}}$ around $\bar{P^0}$ (Having the order 1 expansion is not sufficient for me as the sample size is generally small, $n \ge 4$). I write that,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\hat{\bar{P^0}}} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(\bar{P^0})}{k!} (\hat{\bar{P^0}} - \bar{P^0})^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\bar{P^0}^{k+1}} (\hat{\bar{P^0}} - \bar{P^0})^k
\end{align}
because $D^n(f) = (-1)^k\frac{k!}{x^{k+1}}$. Then, when computing the expectation, we have :
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{\hat{\bar{P}}_0}\right) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\bar{P^0}^{k+1}} \mathbb{E}\left[(\hat{\bar{P^0}} - \bar{P^0})^k \right] \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\bar{P^0}^{k+1}} \mathbb{\mu}_k(\hat{\bar{P^0}})
\end{align}
where $\mathbb{\mu}_k$ is the centered moment of order k.
However, since $\hat{\bar{P^0}}$ is asymptotically normal in distribution then we know the centered moment at every order $k$, that is to say, if $k\ (=: 2h)$ is even then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{\mu}_k(\hat{\bar{P^0}}) &= (k-1)!! \left( \frac{\sigma_0}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^k \\
&= \frac{(2h)!}{2^h h!} \left( \frac{\sigma_0^2}{n}\right)^h
\end{align}
else ($k$ is odd) : $\mathbb{\mu}_k(\hat{\bar{P^0}}) = 0$.
Then I can write
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{\hat{\bar{P}}_0}\right)
&= \sum_{h=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{2h}}{\bar{P^0}^{2h+1}} \frac{(2h)!}{2^h h!} \left( \frac{\sigma_0^2}{n}\right)^h \\
&=  \frac{1}{\bar{P^0}} \sum_{h=0}^\infty \frac{(2h)!}{h!} \left( \frac{\sigma_0^2}{2n \bar{P^0}^2}\right)^h.
\end{align}
If I consider the series $S = \sum_{h \ge 0}\frac{(2h)!}{h!} x^h = \sum_{h \ge 0} u_h$ where $x > 0$ is fixed, I see that this series diverges by the ratio test. Indeed,
$$
\left| \frac{u_{h+1}}{u_{h}} \right| = \frac{(2h+1)(2h+2)}{h+1}x = 2(2h+1)x \rightarrow_{h \rightarrow \infty} + \infty.
$$
This means then that $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{\hat{\bar{P}}_0}\right)$ is non-finite... Which is quite difficult to understand for me, because in the "expected" taylor expansion adding more terms that are $O\left( \frac{1}{n^h}\right)$ would give a more precise aproximation of $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{\hat{\bar{P}}_0}\right)$.
So here is my question. Why do my series diverges even though I think that expanding the "expected" taylor expansion to a greater order would give a more precise aproximation of $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{\hat{\bar{P}}_0}\right)$ ? Are my assumptions wrong ? And if this computation is wrong, what can I do instead ? I don't think there would be a nice simplificating formula for this expectation, but I really want to have a high order expansion so that my expectation is highly precisely approximated since the sample size can be really low.
Thanks in advance (and excuse my English as I am not native).
Steve.

In general for computing $M=E(1/(X_1+\cdots+X_n))$ where $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are positive and iid, and if $f(s)=E(e^{-sX_1})$ is known, one uses
$$\frac{1}{A}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sA}ds$$ and, doing $A=X_1+\cdots X_n$ we get $$M=\int_0^{\infty}f(s)^nds.$$
